# How much is "shared vCPUs" for db-f1-micro in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Regarding the instance of Google Cloud SQL called `db-f1-micro`, how much vCPUs does it refer when saying "shared vCPUs"? Always less than 1 vCPU (this would be the top limit)? Or it can also be more than 1 shared vCPU? Always depending on the circumstances of the moment, of course.

Here there is a link for the service in question: https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing

Answer (score 1):

It can have up to 1 vCPU at max. As indicated in the official documentation [Machine Types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#machine_types):

> N1: f1-micro and g1-small shared-core machine types have up to 1 vCPU available for short periods of bursting.

This way, including the instance `db-f1-micro`.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Yes, `f1-micro` has exactly 0.2 vCPU and 0.6 GB of RAM. But regarding `db-f1-micro` it doesn't specify the number of vCPUs, it just says "shared vCPUs". So I must deduce from here that `db-f1-micro` also has 0.2 vCPU as `f1-micro`?

Comment: Hi @NéstorLlamas yes, you are correct. `db`-f1-micro` follows the same pattern as `f1-micro`.